# How can I use a method Get, of another class to print this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print my array deck, when I use this **printf**,

gives a message like: *"jamilzin.cassino.Deck@28a418fc"*

However when I tried to create a method philippines in my Deck Class,

my printf return message like:
*"jamilzin.cassino.Card@63a418fc"*

How can I use a correct casting to use my **getValue** and **getSuit** to print my array?

**My idea:** create a object Deck(), as Deck is a Array of Card, i want cast something like a  *MyDeck(Card.getValue)*, but idk how to do it

```
    package jamilzin.cassino;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    Deck class: 
    
    public class Deck {
    
        private Card[] deck;
        private String[] suits = {"Ouro", "Paus", "Espada", "Copas"};
        private Random gerador = new Random();
        
        public Deck(){
            deck = new Card[52];
            int k = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j< suits.length;j++){
                for(int i = 0;i< 13;i++){
                    deck[k] = new Card((i+1),suits[j]); 
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }}

--------------------------------
Card class:
package jamilzin.cassino;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {
    
    private String suit;
    private int value;
    
    Card(int value, String suit){
    this.value = 0;
    this.suit = " ";
    
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    ----------------------------------

Test class:

public class Cassino {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
 Deck deckMaster = new Deck();
 System.out.println(""+ deckMaster);
       
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is close. When you call `System.out.println("" + deckMaster)`, the `Deck` doesn't define how it should print itself. You can fix that by adding something like this to the `Deck` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(deck);
}
```

From there, it will print each `Card`, but they also don't know how to print themselves, so you could try adding something like this to the `Card` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getValue() + getSuit();
}
```

Also, your constructor for `Card` is ignoring all input parameters, which is probably not what you want. So change this:

```
Card(int value, String suit) {
    this.value = 0;
    this.suit = " ";
}
```

to this:

```
Card(int value, String suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```